# Parse first word of the command in recognized speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to take `speech` input and convert them to string and show it on the `richtext box` control. I have read about speech synthesis and voice recognition in several articles where I learned to get commands via speech however I want to write on richtext box control after my command `Write` is recognized. Is it possible?

Here is the code if it helps understand what I am trying to achieve and what I have done so far

`object` declarations

```
PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
Choices clist = new Choices();
```

The code for `Enabling` Voice Input

```
 private void btnEnableVoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnEnableVoice.Enabled = false;
        btnDisableVoice.Enabled = true;

        /////////////Adding commands in a list of type Choices///////////////////////
        clist.Add(new string[] { "Is it working", "Write" });
        Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(clist));

        try
        {
            recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate(); ///////starting engine
            recognizer.LoadGrammar(gr);
            recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
            recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
   void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text.ToString())
        { 
            case "Is it working":
                ss.SpeakAsync("Yes its working");
                break;
            case "Write":
                richTextBox1.Text += ""; //Speech to text input here
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something other than adding `e.Result.Text` to `richTextBox1.Text` in the speech recognized event?

Comment: Say for example I say `Write my name is John`. I want to show `my name is John` on the rich text box control i.e to write all the text except the command `Write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to construct a grammar in a proper way to allow dictation, see for the reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576565(v=vs.110).aspx:

```
 Choices clist = new Choices();
 clist.Add(new string[] { "Is it working", "Write" });
 GrammarBuilder bl = new GrammarBuilder(clist);
 bl.appendDictation();
 Grammar gr = new Grammar(bl);
```

To parse you need something like

```
void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) 
     string result = e.Result.Text.ToString();
     if (result.startsWith("Write")) {
         richTextBox1.Text += result.substring(7); // Skip first 6 chars
     } else if (result.startsWith("Is it working")) {
         ss.SpeakAsync("Yes its working");
     }
}
```

Comment: Isn't working. I even tried this
    if (e.Result.Text.StartsWith("Write")
       richTextBox1.Text= e.Result.Text.Replace("Write", string.Empty).Trim();

Comment: The other command is working perfectly. Don't know what's wrong with this.

Comment: Ok, you also need to construct grammar properly, see updated post.